# How is it possible that .coffee files are being included directly by karma even though I have preproccessors defined in my karma.conf?

Tags: coffeescript, karma-runner

## Question

How is it possible that .coffee files are being included directly to my index.html (like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/specs/Demo.coffee"></script>`) by karma even though I have `preproccessors: {'**/*.coffee': 'coffee'}` defined in my `karma.conf.js`? It appears they are not being preprocessed. How can I make them be preprocessed?

## Background

- [my karma.conf.js](https://gist.github.com/Wizek/8e926157f9593ddc6a4a/a8fb2cbbda002e08d48d418e5f775cd7e2156e2f)

  - Note, that `basePath: ''`
  - Also, the different revisions of that Gist show some different variations I tried, none successful.
- `karma start` outputs:

  ```
  INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.1 server started at http://localhost:9876/
  INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
  INFO [Chrome 33.0.1750 (Mac OS X 10.9.2)]: Connected on socket sdb2-kO0hAjpMPQhBJeJ   with id 81292980
  Chrome 33.0.1750 (Mac OS X 10.9.2) ERROR
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at /path/to/repo/specs/Demo.coffee:1

  Chrome 33.0.1750 (Mac OS X 10.9.2) ERROR
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at /path/to/repo/specs/NgLodashSpec.coffee:1

  ...
  ```
- `karma.conf.js` is located at the root of my project folder.
- I run `karma start` at the root of my project folder.
- `coffee --version`: CoffeeScript version 1.7.1
- `karma --version`: Karma version: 0.12.1
- `karma-cli`: 0.0.4
- `karma-coffee-preprocessor`: 0.2.1

There are a lot of things that might be relevant, if you miss something from the above list, tell me and I'll add it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment on Vojta's answer, the question contains a significant spelling error:

`preproccessors` should be `preprocessors`

(posing this as an answer so the question can be tidied up)

Answer (score 1):

All the patterns (including preprocessors) are resolved to `basePath`. Are these files outside of your `basePath`? If so, you need to reference them as `preprocessors: {'../**/*.js': ['coffee']}`.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately my basePath is empty. As far as I can tell karma has no reason to assume anything other than my project root folder as basePath. Added 3 items to the background list: (1) contents of my `karma.conf.js`, (2) `karma.conf.js` located at the root, and (3) `karma start` location is the root directory.

Comment: Just to point out that in the question there is a (probably) significant spelling error that might be the cause of the problem: `preproccessors` should be `preprocessors`

Comment: @myitcv Oh my, you are correct! Thank you for noticing! The strange thing is that it was written like that for a long time so I just assumed the error couldn't be there. Functions that take hashmaps as arguments should really warn for unrecognized options... But I digress; myitcv, If you make your comment it into an answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: No need to credit me. Just fix up your question so that others don't copy and paste the wrong thing!